# How to use avoid shrink on flex by overflowing horiontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am trying to make a tree like structure using flex. When I was using flex with `justify-content: space-around;` I am facing an error.

```css
.root {
    margin-top: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.branch {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main problem is width of `item` should be same, but flex is trying to `space-around` but by compromising width. What I want is it should `space-around` with `overflow-x` if needed. But, should not shrink **item**.

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the root element `inline-flex` instead of `flex`

```css
.root {
    margin-top: 40px;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.branch {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow!!!!! It was too easy who already knew about that!!! Thank you... It worked! But, little references and explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: when using flex your element is restricted by the width of the parent (like any block element) but and inline element will match its content width and the parent width restriction no more apply

Comment: but parents width was ```min-width``` ... Then, ```flex``` should have allowed right???

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane you applied min-width to the root element which is useless when dealing when having `display:flex` because the element is alreadt width:100% by default. min-width will add nothing. using inline-flex will make it shrink-to-fit and here the min-width will help you having at least the width of the parent and more if needed. It's like the difference between block and inline-block

Answer (score 1):

If you want achieve this by making your root element as  block then put **overflow:auto** in **.root class** and in **.item  class** add f**lex-shrink:0**.

```css
.root {
    margin-top: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow:auto;
}
.branch {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes... This way also, it worked!! I was adding ```flex-shrink``` on branch !!! Thank you!!!